# how to do aggregate after doing createIndexex in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb

I want to optimize my query as much as possible. So I found a method called "createIndexes". But I am not getting how to use it along with "aggregate".

```
    db.createIndexes({age:1})
    .then(_ => {
        return db.aggregate(
           [
              {"$match":{"age":age}},
              {"$group":{
                 _id: '$name',
                 hobby:{$addToSet:'$hobby'}    
              }},
              {$project:{
                 _id:0,
                 name:'$_id',
                 hobbyCount:{$size:'$hobby'}
              }}
           ]
      })
```

I want to put the index in the age column and then want to do the aggregate operation but the indexing is not happening. Anyone any idea why this is not working?

Answer (score 0):

`createIndexes()` is an one time operation. Once you call this method, the indexes will be built and all the subsequent queries will use the indexes whenever possible.

That said, `createIndexes` does not affect how you call normally `aggregate`.

Comment: k what you are trying to say is if I use this createIndexes on onload of the page then all the subsequent query will use the indexes implicitly?

Comment: Yes. But you should not build the indexes during `onload`. As building indexes is usually time-consuming, you should create the indexes before serving the website to others.

Comment: any scenario when I should use createIndexes so that my query will not consume much time?

Comment: Practically, you should always have indexes, as it speeds up querying time. Otherwise, you would have to perform a full db scan when you run even a simple query.  
For example, you can have a `createIndexes.js` which create the indexes. You run the script once and all the indexes will be there whenever you query the related fields

Comment: so createIndexes.js i can trigger during login time only so that any time in entire project the indexes will be there right?

Comment: That's correct. How many time would you login though? You really do not need to run the `createIndexes.js` more than once.